# Show div when selection from dropdown contains a certain word

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is make a div fade in upon a selection being made from a dropdown that must contain a certain word within its string.

So far I have had it appear instantly on page load before a selection is made and now I have it where it doesn't show despite a selection being made - any pointers, please?

```js
if ($("select option:selected[value*='tailboard']")) {
  $("#tcanopy .towbar_req").fadeIn("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select style="font-family: Arial;" name="trailermodel" required>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Trailer Model</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD64 Ramp">GD64 with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD64 Tailboard">GD64 with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD84 Ramp">GD84 with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD84 Tailboard">GD84 with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD85 Ramp">GD85 with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD85 Tailboard">GD85 with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P6e Ramp">P6e with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P6e Tailboard">P6e with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P6e Livestock">P6e Livestock Model</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P7e Ramp">P7e with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P7e Tailboard">P7e with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P7e Livestock">P7e Livestock Model</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P8e Ramp">P8e with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P8e Tailboard">P8e with Tailboard</option>
</select>
<div class="towbar_req">
  <p>Requirements (if tailboard*):</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? and provide your HTML code too please.

Comment: Nothing happens when selecting an option that contains tailboard (I want it to fade in the .towbar_req div)

Comment: The answers below are guesses, based on the little information you've given us.  You need to post the relevant markup, as well as the relevant code.  Also, is your script just this `if` statement, or is there more to it?

Comment: @Archer it's just a basic dropdown which I have now added, nothing else in the script currently besides the doc ready.

Comment: So your script is literally `<script>` then the `if` statement and then `</script>`?  Also, your markup doesn't include anything that will be selected with `$("#tcanopy .towbar_req")`.

Comment: #tcanopy is the div holding the dropdown and .towbar_req div. Yes just the document ready followed by the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't assign your code to run when the dropdown value changes.  What you have will run once, when the document has loaded (as per your comment about document.ready).  You need to wrap the logic in an appropriate event handler, like this...

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    if (RegExp(/tailboard/i).test($(this).val()) {
        $("#tcanopy .towbar_req").fadeIn("slow");    
    }
    else {
        $("#tcanopy .towbar_req").fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
```

With that, every time anything matching `$("select")` changes, the code will be executed.  Bear this in mind if you add any more select elements to the page.  You may want to give it an ID and select it with that instead.

Secondly, your code would look for `tailboard` in the selected value, but your values don't have that in them - they have `Tailboard` (uppercase T).

The code above uses a regular expression to look for `tailboard` in the value, but is case insensitive so should solve your problem.

---

Here's a working example.

**Note:** I included CSS to set the initial state of the element you want to toggle.

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {

    // show/hide tailboard related div
    if (RegExp(/tailboard/i).test($(this).val())) {
        $("#tcanopy .towbar_req").fadeIn("slow");    
    }
    else {
        $("#tcanopy .towbar_req").fadeOut("slow");
    }

    // show/hide ramp related div
    if (RegExp(/ramp/i).test($(this).val())) {
        $("#tcanopy .ramp_req").fadeIn("slow");    
    }
    else {
        $("#tcanopy .ramp_req").fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
```

```css
.towbar_req,
.ramp_req {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tcanopy">
    <select name="trailermodel" required>
        <option style="font-family: Arial;" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Trailer Model</option>
        <option value="GD64 Ramp">GD64 with Ramp</option>
        <option value="GD64 Tailboard">GD64 with Tailboard</option>
        <option value="GD84 Ramp">GD84 with Ramp</option>
        <option value="GD84 Tailboard">GD84 with Tailboard</option>
        <option value="GD85 Ramp">GD85 with Ramp</option>
        <option value="GD85 Tailboard">GD85 with Tailboard</option>
        <option value="P6e Ramp">P6e with Ramp</option>
        <option value="P6e Tailboard">P6e with Tailboard</option>
        <option value="P6e Livestock">P6e Livestock Model</option>
        <option value="P7e Ramp">P7e with Ramp</option>
        <option value="P7e Tailboard">P7e with Tailboard</option>
        <option value="P7e Livestock">P7e Livestock Model</option>
        <option value="P8e Ramp">P8e with Ramp</option>
        <option value="P8e Tailboard">P8e with Tailboard</option>
    </select>
    <div class="towbar_req">
        <p>Requirements (if tailboard*):</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ramp_req">
        <p>Requirements (if ramp*):</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't relaise about the case sensitivity so thank you for that, unfortunately, again, nothing happens even with this script though Dreamweaver shows a syntax error on this line: if (RegExp(/tailboard/i).test($(this).val()) {

Comment: Ignore Dreamweaver - run it and look in the browser console for errors.

Comment: I did that first which shows an error on the same line as above - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo - a missing closing `)`.  I've fixed it and added a snippet

Comment: Thank you thats cracked it! Now I want to understand how so will do a bit of research. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Comment: can I ask a silly q? I want to add a second one (looking for ramp) adding that same code after the initial snippet you gave me and changing the regexp to ramp doesn't work and all other combo's I have tried have a failed miserably too...any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to find them both with `$("select")` or have you given them both an ID so you can select them with those instead?  Alternatively, use `$("#tcanopy select")` and then put the other select elements inside divs with different IDs and change that selector to suit.

Comment: I was using the select name of trailermodel - the tailboard still worked but ramp did nothing, obviously both sets of options whether it be tailboard or ramp are all within that same dropdown, just trigger different divs to fade in or out.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.  I'll update the answer to include something appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `onchange` event in the `select` dropdown so that when you select the option it fades in:

```js
function changeSelect(){
  var selected = $("select option:selected[value*='tailboard']");
  if (selected.length) {
    $("#tcanopy .towbar_req").fadeIn("slow");
  }
}

//check on page load
changeSelect();
```

```css
.towbar_req {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange = "changeSelect()">
  <option value=""> select </option>
  <option value="tailboard text"> tailboard 1 </option>
  <option value="text"> some other text</option>
  <option value="123 tailboard text"> tailboard text 123</option>
</select>

<div id = 'tcanopy'>
  <div class='towbar_req'>
    Fade in fade out
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fade in fade out stays there even when selection option 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can have change event handler and check value of select box. if it contains `tailborad` then show div

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    var show = $(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("tailboard")!=-1;
    if(show) {
     $("#tcanopy .towbar_req").fadeIn("slow");
    }
}}
```

Comment: unfortunately still nothing happens - the option contains more words than just tailboard if that could be the issue?

Comment: `Tailboard` starts with capital T and i had written with small. We can use `toLowerCase()` function as this will catch Tailboard with call type of letters. Please see updated post

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/dcv9je7s/1/)**.

You need to attach a `change` event listener to the select, then check if the selected option value contains the `Tailboard` word using `.indexOf()`.

**Shorthand:**

```
$('select[name="trailermodel"]').on('change', function() {
   $("#tcanopy .towbar_req").toggle($(this).val().indexOf("Tailboard") != -1);
});
```

```js
$('select[name="trailermodel"]').on('change', function() {
  var target = $("#tcanopy .towbar_req");

  if ($(this).val().indexOf("Tailboard") != -1) {
      target.fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
      target.fadeOut("slow");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select style="font-family: Arial;" name="trailermodel" required>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Trailer Model</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD64 Ramp">GD64 with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD64 Tailboard">GD64 with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD84 Ramp">GD84 with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD84 Tailboard">GD84 with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD85 Ramp">GD85 with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="GD85 Tailboard">GD85 with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P6e Ramp">P6e with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P6e Tailboard">P6e with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P6e Livestock">P6e Livestock Model</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P7e Ramp">P7e with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P7e Tailboard">P7e with Tailboard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P7e Livestock">P7e Livestock Model</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P8e Ramp">P8e with Ramp</option>
  <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="P8e Tailboard">P8e with Tailboard</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="tcanopy">
  <span class="towbar_req" style="display:none">Target Element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why you didn't choose the `indexOf()` solution when it's faster than regex when searching for a substring? **[Check the substring test short haystack](https://jsperf.com/substring-test)**.